# Unable to show a Border/Stroke when clicking on an ImageButton

Tags: android, border, imagebutton

I am working with `ImageButtons` but I am not able to create a border when clicking on them. I know that there is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842138/how-can-i-make-make-a-border-for-a-clicked-imagebutton-in-android) regarding this topic but after following the answer, I have not been able to make it work.

Currently my code is:

**ib_shape_corner.xlm**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="@color/blue1" />
    <padding
        android:left="3dp"
        android:top="3dp"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:bottom="3dp" />
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="8dip"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dip"
        android:topRightRadius="8dip"
        android:topLeftRadius="8dip" />
</shape>
```

**ib_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ib_shape_corner" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

**main.xml**

```
 <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib_img"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ib_selector"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_img"
            android:padding="5dp">
```

**main.java**

Here I have tried setting to pressed and to selected my button when clicking on it but it has not worked

```
    ib_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ib_img.setSelected(true);
            ib_img.setPressed(true);
           // Do my stuff

        }
    });
```

The `listener` works since it actually run my code when clicking but the border is not added.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:clickable="true"
```

for your ImageButton.